# Looping concepts program

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I have been trying to learn Java and have played around a bit with different concepts for a short while. I decided to make a loop program to further cement my knowledge of the different types of loops.

The program below is designed to accept a user input, create a different variable in each loop class that I made and loop that number of times increasing the integer by 1.
e.g

"enter input" 
2

foreach 1
foreach 2
while 1
while 2
for 1
for 2

however the output that I am getting is entirely different after making the program. I get For loops up to 49 +- 1 for each number higher/lower the user inputs and for each repeating 0 49 times. The While loop does not run. After googling and looking around on StackOverflow I cannot for the life of me work out why my program does not work.

---

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoopPlay {
    static int loopNumber = 0;
    public static void main (String [] args){
        System.out.println ("Please enter a number to loop by");
        try {
            loopNumber = System.in.read();
            ForLoop.DoLoop();
            WhileLoop.DoLoop();
            EnhancedForLoop.DoLoop();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Did you enter an integer?");
            main(args);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}



public class ForLoop extends LoopPlay{
    static int loops = LoopPlay.loopNumber;
    public static void DoLoop (){
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<loops; i++){
            System.out.println ("Forloop = " + i);
        }
    }
}



public class WhileLoop extends LoopPlay {
    static int loops = LoopPlay.loopNumber;
    public static void DoLoop(){
        int i = LoopPlay.loopNumber;
        while (i < loops){
            System.out.println("Whileloop =" + loops);
            loops++;
        }
    }
}



public class EnhancedForLoop extends LoopPlay {

    static int [] loop = new int [LoopPlay.loopNumber];
    static int loops = LoopPlay.loopNumber;

    public static void ForLoop (String [] args){
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<loops; i++){
            loop[i] = i;
        }
    }
    public static void DoLoop () {
        for (int x : loop){
            System.out.println("EnhancedForLoop = " + x);
        }
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have continued to play around with the looping program and now my for and while loop methods are running exactly as I want them to however I cannot get my enhanced for loop method to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Import scanner class for reading user input

public class LoopPlay { // Sets the loopNumber and allows user to select loop type

    static int loopNumber = 0; // Instantiates loopNumber for calculating num of times to loop
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // Creates a scanner object called scan

public static void main (String [] args){ // Primary method 
    System.out.println ("Please enter a number to loop by"); // Asks user for input

    loopNumber = scan.nextInt(); // Sets loopNumber to user input

    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"); // Clears the console
    System.out.println("What would you like to do?"); // Menu for user selections 
    System.out.println("1. For Loop");
    System.out.println("2. While Loop");
    System.out.println("3. Enhanced For Loop");
    System.out.println("4. Do all");

    int choice = scan.nextInt(); // Sets user choice to choice variable
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    switch (choice){ // Creates a switch statement to call loops based on choice
    case 1: choice = 1;
    ForLoop.DoLoop();
    break;

    case 2: choice = 2;
    WhileLoop.DoLoop();
    break;

    case 3: choice = 3;
    EnhancedForLoop.DoLoop();
    break;

    case 4: choice = 4;
    ForLoop.DoLoop();
    WhileLoop.DoLoop();
    EnhancedForLoop.DoLoop();
    }
}
}





public class WhileLoop extends LoopPlay { // This class runs a while loop using       loopNumber
public static void DoLoop(){
    int i = loopNumber; // Sets i to loop variable for this method
    while (i > 0 ){ // Outputs the value of i for loopNumber amount of times
        System.out.println("Whileloop = " + i);
        i--;
    }
    LoopPlay.main(null); // Calls the main method to restart process
}
```

}

```
public class ForLoop extends LoopPlay{ // Class for While Loop
public static void DoLoop (){
    int i; // Creates a looping variable local to DoLoop method
    for (i=loopNumber; i > 0; i--){ // Sets i to loop variable and loops that many times
        System.out.println ("Forloop = " + i); // Shows where the loop is up to
    }
    LoopPlay.main(null); // Restarts the program
}
```

}

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;


public class EnhancedForLoop extends LoopPlay { // Class to run through using an enhanced for loop

static int enhancedLoop = (loopNumber); // creates an array with loopNumber amount of slots

public static void ForLoop (String [] args){ // Populates the enhancedLoop array
    int i;                                   // with values of i
    for (i=loopNumber; i > 0; i--){
        enhancedLoop(i) = i;
    }
}
public static void DoLoop () { // Runs the enhanced loop to display all values of enhancedLoop
    for (int x: enhancedLoop){
        System.out.println("EnhancedForLoop = " + x);
    }
    LoopPlay.main(null); // Restarts the program
}
```

}

Comment: You are not resetting your loopNumber after each run, causing the while loop to immediately exit.

Comment: I would avoid using static in almost every variable you declare as well. Although I guess it's required in this case.

Comment: You're initializing `i` and `loops` to the same value (the current value of `LoopPlay.loopNumber`) in `WhileLoop`. the condition `(i < loops)` can therefore never be true, and the while loop will never be entered.